# Sharepoint - CQWP to point to current site

Tags: sharepoint, cqwp

In an ONET.XML file I build a page with a CQWP.  The CQWP has a WebUrl property is there a way to set this to alway be the the current web?

I tried this but it didn't work.s

```
<AllUsersWebPart WebPartZoneID="g_LeftCell" WebPartOrder="1" >
      <![CDATA[
      <webParts>
...

<property name="WebUrl" type="string">~Site</property>
```

Answer (score 2):

That should work. I can find a couple examples where we have done that before. I don't know if it makes any difference, but one onet had:

```
<property name="WebUrl" type="string">~Site</property>
```

and another had:

```
<property name="WebUrl" type="string">~site</property>
```

But since both versions are working, I don't think the case on Site makes any difference.